# Google App Engineで使えるJavaフレームワーク

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Google App Engine上でも使えるJavaのフレームワークは何ですか？実サービスとしての運用経験があると大歓迎。

そこまで本格的でなくても、検証レベルの使ってみた感想でも良いです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

弊社(株式会社トップゲート)のSystemは、ほぼ全てSlim3で作られています。

書籍としては、[Google API Expertが解説する Google App Engine for Java実践ガイド](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4844331736)もサンプルコードはSlim3で書かれています。

とりあえず、試してみよう！という場合は、[slim3 quickstart](http://qiita.com/sinmetal/items/b23088bad52a9c782aed)にProjectの作り方を書いておきました。

後、Slim3のVersionですが、
今のところ、そんなに活発に機能追加などはされておりませんので、最新versionのスナップショットを使うのが良いかなと思います。

その他GAE/Jのlibraryとして、Datastore周りだと、[objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/)があります。
こちらは僕は触ってないのですが、DatastoreのFrontにMemcacheを自動的に利用してくれる機能があります。
この機能が欲しい場合は、objectifyを選ぶのも良いかと思います。

Comment: 実際のシステム運用実績について教えていただけたのが良いなと思ったのでチェックマークをこちらに変更しました。

Comment: stackoverflowあんまり慣れてなくて、zakiさんのCommentに追加で書いた気分になっていたので、zakiさんのCommentも合わせて読んでいただければ、幸いです！

Answer (score 7):

私がGAE/Java でコードを書くときは [Slim3](http://slim3.org/) を使っています。

- [Slim3 公式サイト](http://slim3.org/)
- [Slim3 日本語サイト(非公式)](https://sites.google.com/site/slim3documentja/)

テストコードがとても書きやすくなるのがよいです。

もし Slim3 を使うのであれば http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4798026999 がおすすめです。
出版されてから4年経っているので記述が古くなっている部分があるかもしれませんが、使い方からテストの書き方まで丁寧に説明されていてわかりやすかったです。

Answer (score 3):

[Ninja framework](http://www.ninjaframework.org/)という面白そうなのがあったのでメモしておきます。

Google App Engine用のやつ
https://github.com/ninjaframework/ninja-appengine

Answer (score 3):

当社では、Slim3をベースに独自拡張したフレームワークを作成しております。
最近はあまり更新されないのでSlim3利用部分は随分なくなって来てますが。。
来年どこかでオープンソースとして公開する予定です。
エラーレベルによっては自動でメールが飛ぶとか、
DataStoreEditor（エクセルのようにコピペ出来る）とかがあります。

Answer (score 1):

slim3が大変使いやすい。
ひがさんがあまり活動しなくなっちゃったので、今後の更新がどうなるのかが心配ですが。

遊びや検証で作ったアプリを動かしたり、iPhoneアプリ(ダウンロード数は10万程度)のサーバー側としても使ったりしています。

不満がないので他のを探したことがないです。

Answer (score 1):

個人でいくつか使いましたが、正直Slim3一択かなと思います。
Slim3が優れているのはもちろんですが、他にまともなものがありません。
何よりもSlim3であればスピンロック問題に悩まされることがありません。

Answer (score 1):

こちらではSpring Tool Suiteで開発したWebサービスをGAEで運用しています。
認証・権限はSpring-Security、画面やrest apiにはSpringMVCなどを使っています。